# Force Maven Shade Plugin to apply latest SNAPSHOT dependency in a multi-module build

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am using the maven-shade-plugin in a multi-module build to generate a shaded JAR.

Everything works as expected, except that SNAPSHOT dependencies from my modules do not get updated unless I clean the aggregate project.

```
pom.xml
  |
  +-a/pom.xml (a-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)
  |
  +-b/pom.xml (b-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)
  |
  +-aggregate/pom.xml (a_and_b-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar)
```

In the example, the aggregate project builds the shaded jar. The aggregate project lists "b" as a dependency, and "b" lists "a" as a dependency. If I make a change to code in "a" and run "mvn install" from the parent directory, "a" is rebuilt but the shaded JAR does not contain the updated "a".

Previously, I used the dependency and assembly plugins to create the fat jar file. The dependency plugin provides this behaviour with the overWriteIfNewer and overwriteSnapshots options. I can do a "mvn clean -pl aggregate; mvn install", but want to know if there is a similar shade plugin option for me to force the shade plugin to pull in newer dependencies?

I am using apache-maven-3.3.9 and version 2.4.3 of the maven-shade-plugin.

Comment: It should. That's because you're incorrectly using Maven. You should launch `mvn clean install` from the root POM.

Comment: The example I provided is simple. The actual project is quite large, and cleaning everything each time a single line of code is changed is not desirable.